# Add bank account payment method

Tags: checkout, payment, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I'm trying to add a bank account number to the payment method in the checkout but i can't find the option in the magento back end, where should i look this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is free extension availabel

[Click here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bankpayment.html)

> Note::I am not promoting this extension just found in google result
>   that's why placed here